# how to build and train an lstm network in tensorflow.js

Tags: node.js, lstm, tensorflow.js

I am trying to build and train an lstm network using tensorflow.js, my data set is like

Input: "I don't like these shoes, they are too yellow for me. so returning them."
Expected output reason: "color"

I can present the text as vectors using a pre-trained word2vec model.
Tried reading the documentation [tensorflow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.0/#layers.lstm) but I could not make much sense from it, even from other sources could not find a good example on how to implement and train a network in tensorflow.js.

Can anyone please present a straight example of creating the model with LSTM layers and training it using node.js and tensorflow.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of an RNN with multi-layer LSTM that implements Word2Vec. I don't think you'll need to tweak it much to match your use case- probably only the data source and the hyperparameters. Of course, you'll need to write your own testing function too. Since you said you can supply your own pre-trained Word2Vec vectors, you can also probably remove a significant proportion of the code if you like.

I should note- I wrote this example and my preference is to use a library called [Numjs](https://github.com/numjs) to create vectors (it's a similar library to Numpy) and then convert those into tensors which Tensorflow.js uses. This isn't exactly the way Tensorflow.js was designed to be used, but I found their method of creating tensors to be too cumbersome and unintuitive.

Anyway, here's my example (with node.js). I hope you find it useful.

```
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const fs = require('fs');
var nj = require('numjs');

const maxlen = 30;
const step = 3;
fs.readFile(<file>, 'utf8', function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var text = data.toString();
    create_model(text)
});


function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function indexOfMax(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    var max = arr[0];
    var maxIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            maxIndex = i;
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}

function sample(preds, temperature) {
  preds = nj.array(preds, 'float64');
  preds = nj.log(preds).divide(temperature)
  exp_preds = nj.exp(preds)
  preds = exp_preds.divide(nj.sum(exp_preds))
  arr = preds.tolist()
  return indexOfMax(arr)
}

async function create_model(text) {
  /* data prep */
  text = text.toLowerCase()
  console.log('corpus length:', text.length)
  var words = text.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm," ").split(" ")
  words = words.filter(onlyUnique)
  words = words.sort()
  words = words.filter(String)

  console.log("total number of unique words" + words.length)

  var word_indices = {}
  var indices_word = {}
  for (let e0 of words.entries()) {
    var idx = e0[0]
    var word = e0[1]
    word_indices[word] = idx
    indices_word[idx] = word
  }

  console.log("maxlen: " + maxlen, " step: " + step)

  var sentences = []
  var sentences1 = []

  var next_words = []
  list_words = text.toLowerCase().replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm," ").split(" ").filter(String)
  console.log('list_words ' + list_words.length)

  for (var i = 0; i < (list_words.length - maxlen); i += step) {
    var sentences2 = list_words.slice(i, i + maxlen).join(" ")
    sentences.push(sentences2)
    next_words.push(list_words[i + maxlen])
  }
  console.log('nb sequences(length of sentences):', sentences.length)
  console.log("length of next_word", next_words.length)

  console.log('Vectorization...')
  var X = nj.zeros([sentences.length, maxlen, words.length])
  console.log('X shape' + X.shape)
  var y = nj.zeros([sentences.length, words.length])
  console.log('y shape' + y.shape)
  for (let e of sentences.entries()) {
    var i = e[0]
    var sentence = e[1]
    for (let e2 of sentence.split(" ").entries()) {
      var t = e2[0]
      var word = e2[1]
      X.set(i, t, word_indices[word], 1)
    }
    y.set(i, word_indices[next_words[i]], 1)
  }

  console.log('Creating model... Please wait.');

  console.log("MAXLEN " + maxlen + ", words.length " + words.length)
  var model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.lstm({
    units: 128,
    returnSequences: true,
    inputShape: [maxlen, words.length]
  }));
  model.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.2))
  model.add(tf.layers.lstm({
    units: 128,
    returnSequences: false
  }));
  model.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.2))
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: words.length, activation: 'softmax'}));

  model.compile({loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', optimizer: tf.train.rmsprop(0.002)});

  x_tensor = tf.tensor3d(X.tolist(), null, 'bool')
  //x_tensor.print(true)
  y_tensor = tf.tensor2d(y.tolist(), null, 'bool')
  //y_tensor.print(true)

  /* training */
  await model.fit(x_tensor, y_tensor, {
    epochs: 100,
    batchSize: 32,
    callbacks: {
      onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
        console.log(logs.loss + ",")
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: I am still stuck on converting my input and outputs to tensor3d, I am trying like this var input = tf.tensor3d(dataArray); and dataArray = [ [length 300], [length 300]. . .], giving out Error: tensor3d() requires values to be number[][][] or flat/TypedArray, can you point out if i am missing anything.

Comment: sorry i did not get time to try it. just started again working on it. tensor2d() should work i believe, can you explain a little bit about how to chose input shape, let say my data set is like array of objects and each object is having input paragraph, and output sentence. but the length of the paragraph is not fixed.

Comment: @Manoj You need to pad the input with null values to fill or cut input vectors up/down to a predefined size (usually determined dynamically). You can either use pre-padding (null values attached to beginning) or post-padding. I can recommend tutorials but they will not be written in Tensorflow.js, unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure about padding or cutting the vectors, my actual inputs are a transcription from customer care calls so calls might be 1 hour long or just few minutes. If those mentioned tutorials are in python, I can try to manage.

Comment: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDByc9LyMV8) is the tutorial I followed for the exact same scenario as you are having. The guy explains the theory first without diving into any python code so hopefully it is useful to you.